# Golang + Linux + Docker error : standard_init_linux.go:211 : no such file or directory

Tags: linux, docker, go

This is not a duplicate because although the error is same, my use case is different from others.

I am compiling a go application to deploy with docker on:

- latest arch linux
- latest docker version, golang:alpine image
- tried with go version 1.13.3 and 1.14.4  linux amd64
- i have no bash scripts or wrong file endings. Whole project is written on this Linux machine
- i can deploy an empty go app that has only a fmt print without any error

however,

when i build it on my OSX machine, and send it to linux, I can deploy that executable to docker without any error

- OSX mojave
- latest docker
- go 1.13.3
- GOOS=linux

Error :

`standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`

Comment: Share Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml

Comment: We'll try to verify that this file exits within the container first, `docker run -it <image_name> bash`, check if this file exists at the specified position, check the file permissions on it usind `ls -l`, is it executable? Then try to invoke this command inside the container.

Comment: i can execute it normally without any errors, updated

Comment: How about `docker run -it <image_name> /bin/sh`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216863/discussion-between-frozenone-and-aomerk).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you compile your go app with `cgo` enabled the compiler links dynamically to `libstdc` .

However, `golang:alpine` image is so small, because it is not using `libstdc` but a simplified version of it called `musl libc`.

The error message says

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

If you connect to your image with

```
$ docker run -it [image] /bin/sh
```

you can find your executable in let's say `/dist/myexec`, but when you try to run that executable, it says `err not found`, because of not that it can't find your executable, obviously, but it can't find file `libc` .

The solution is to either

- disable CGO : use `CGO_ENABLED=0` while building
- or add

  ```
  RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
  ```

  to your `Dockerfile`
- or do not use `golang:alpine`

To have a all static binary executable, build it with:

```
$ CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' .
```